# foreign key select only one record from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server 2012. I have two table, M_SALES & M_SALES_COUNTRY. M_SALES contains a primary key called sale_id. M_SALES_COUNTRY also contains a field called sale_id which is its foreign key. M_SALES_COUNTRY also contain a field called country_code, this field can be null.

So M_SALES contain a unique sale_id. M_SALES_COUNTRY can contain multiple sale_ids which are the same.

For the query below 1 record from the M_SALES_COUNTRY (there could be multiple but I only want one) is returned for each sales_id in the M_SALES table, which is fine and what I want. However I want to know if it is possible to add a further condition.

If the sale_id in M_SALES reference multiple sale_id's in M_SALES_COUNTRY I would like it to return a record where the country_code field is not null. If all the records country_code are null then return null. Please see the two simple examples below.

```
 sale_id     country_code   
 AAA5555     null
 AAA5555     null
 AAA5555     D56
```

record I would like returned is D56.

Next example

```
 sale_id     country_code   
 AAA5555     null
 AAA5555     null
 AAA5555     null
```

any record would do here as long as one is returned.

**Query**

```
 select M_SALES.*, M_SALES_COUNTRY.*
 from M_SALES cross apply
 (
    select top 1 M_SALES_COUNTRY.*
    from M_SALES_COUNTRY
    where M_SALES.sale_id = M_SALES_COUNTRY.sale_id     
  ) MA_DEALS_COUNTRY
  order by M_SALES.sale_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could eliminate duplicates with a subquery and join to that table i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM M_SALES 
JOIN (SELECT sales_id, max(country_code) as country_code
                    FROM M_SALES_COUNTRY GROUP BY sales_id
    ) M_SALES_COUNTRY
ON M_SALES_COUNTRY.sales_id = M_SALES.sales_id
```

I would also consider either cleaning up the M_Sales_Country table so that sales_id would be unique, or create another version of it which contains unique values for a sales id.